# Android usability testing - colorblindness

Tags: android, testing, colors, user-experience, color-blindness

Is there a tool or filter which renders the full Android GUI in grayscale, or a selected app?  I want to do usability testing for color blindness, and I thought that would be a decent way to do it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A downvote with no comment, bad form IMHO. To you it may be obvious how to improve the question, but maybe not to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac OS -> Sim Daltonism (http://michelf.ca/projects/sim-daltonism/)